# Move entire git directory

Tags: git, github

I have `~/.emacs.d/` where I have initialized `git` and connected it with a github repo. Now I realize I need to not have my personal `.emacs.d/` be the master doing the pushes, rather, I need to create an "agnostic" depersonalized version of my `.emacs.d/` . Can I simply copy the whole `~/.emacs.d/` directory -- `.git` and all -- to a new location, say, `~/pure/.emacs.d/` and start using that as the base of the original github repo? Or are there things in `.git` that tie it to that original `~/.emacs.d/ location?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no path based tie-ups in git. The directory that contains `.git` will be the root of your repository. you can move around the root directory without loosing anything.

so just do

```
cp -R ~/.emacs.d ~/pure/
```

And you can checkout the branches in ~/pure/.emacs.d

```
cd ~/pure/.emacs.d && git checkout master
```

You may use this new path to incorporate "Agnostic" changes while keeping the old commits intact

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/.git`